# How to use true async file I/O in dotnet core on Linux?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linux, .net-core

I was trying to understand how dotnet core implements async file I/O on Linux. I check the source file of [FileStream.Unix.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/5bc2806f33090e78b38fafe4d5b46d5a0a4c1f08/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/IO/FileStream.Unix.cs#L720-L722)

And I see a comment like this in WriteAsyncInternal method:

> // The options available on Unix for writing asynchronously to an arbitrary file
>   // handle typically amount to just using another thread to do the synchronous write,
>   // which is exactly  what this implementation does.

So it seems it just using another thread to do synchronous I/O.

My questions are:

1. Isn't there options in Linux to do true async file I/O? Why not use them?
2. Is there any APIs in dotnet core that uses true async file I/O on Linux?

Comment: What do you consider to be 'true async'? If you backup a little and look at this, this implementation might be correct.

Comment: @Rick I mean something like I/O Completion Ports on windows, and that's what they use in FileStream.Windows.cs

Comment: There are two buffers.  One from the app to a temporary buffer.  And a 2nd from the temporary buffer to the file.  The 1st the application writes.  The 2nd the operating system uses.  So from c# you are moving data from your code to a temporary memory buffer that runs extremely fast.  So Async does have any advantages in moving memory to memory.  The slower transfer is the second where the operating system is moving memory to a file.  This only applies to writes and not reads.

Comment: @Student222 One of the benefits of I/O Completion Ports is that it uses a pre-allocated thread pool. In unix systems, a sh*t load is a file... I'd think the OS has enough file I/O optimizations? Wondering if there are benchmarks using these APIs on Windows / Linux... (I'm no expert. This question did make me curious)

Comment: @jdweng I agree that the slower part is from memory to a file. And that's the place async I/O makes sense. I want to know how can we leverage async I/O system APIs in dotnet on Linux?

Comment: What do you mean by leverage?  In Linux you can set priority of a task which may help.  It is not usually operating system that slows down a I/O in Linux.  It is usually the application and changing priority of app in linux works (not like windows).

Comment: @jdweng My understanding of async I/O does not use a Thread, like described here ([There Is No Thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html)) and here ([Async in depth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/async-in-depth#deeper-dive-into-tasks-for-an-io-bound-operation)). This is not about thread priorities.

Comment: Not a user thread, but the kernel is still a thread and show up in the process list. I do not think it is an ASYNC issue, but the apps priority.  The async method in the app has less priority that an operating system async method.  There may be another process on the machine that is slowing down your app.

Comment: The glibc implementation of the posix async I/o api uses threads. There are a few aio related syscalls but nothing ever actually used them - glibc doesn't even provide wrappers for calling them from C. Look up `io_setup(2)` and friends if you're interested. There is a libaio that exports those syscalls.